# How to change gradient cell image color when select cell to navigate another viewcontroller class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

[below cell selected image an gradient image every cell have an gradient image but when select any cell to navigate to another class gradient cell color should be orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaRcc.png)

Cell have already an image (of size 320 * 103) and text- Highs And Lows from The 'Raly To Restore Sanity And' as shown in first cell.

My problem is that when I select any row for navigating to the detailsViewController the cellimage(of size 320 * 103) color should be change as like shown in below imageColor(orange color) (eg. third row). How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

please check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553746/how-to-change-the-blue-highlight-color-of-a-uitableviewcell) which will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView*    paneon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 330, 139)];
    [paneon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bc-pane-01-on.png"]];//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", todo.empphoto]]];
    paneon.opaque = YES; 

    cell.selectedBackgroundView=paneon;
```

Thanks

Arun kumar OD