# Can not set background image for table cell in GROUPED TABLE VIEW iOS 4

Tags: ios5, uitableview, ios4, colors, background-color

If I use following line in iOS 5 + its working perfectly.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2];
```

But this is not working in iOS 4. I also tried following but its not working.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2];
    }
}
```

If I set color in willDisplayCell , its showing me black background for cell.
How can I set background cell color which will work in both iOS 4 & iOS 5.

Any knid of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please refer this link for setting cell background image 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715572/tableview-how-change-the-cell-default-blue-color/9715778#9715778

Comment: Thanks for the link. But my problem solved already. Problem is with line [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2]; It should be [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.2];