# How to change blue highlight color when a cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know it's probably a duplicate, but I want to know the best and the fastest way to change the blue highlight color when a cell is selected.

Of curse, I already tried (and it works) the way which consist in **change the background color when the cell is selected** (like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265662/how-to-change-color-of-uitableviewcell-when-selecting?rq=1)) but I don't like this way, I would prefer to really change this highlight color.

Any link or idea ? Thanks.

Comment: You can give selectedBackgrounndView to your tablecell. This is the most right approach to do it.

Comment: how u r creating ur table view..

Comment: The blue color is relative to a `selectedBackgroundView` property ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553746/how-to-change-the-blue-highlight-color-of-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998775/uitableview-cell-selected-color

Answer (score 7, accepted):

inside tableview's

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Create a uiimageview and change it's background color to your desired color

```
if (cell == nil) {
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
}
```

Comment: @Lucien apply this answer .it is perfect.

Comment: Yes, I didn't watch this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998775/uitableview-cell-selected-color), and the best answer (for me) is not the one applied.

Comment: Hum it's a good answer but what if I want to keep the tint effect ? :/

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating your table view cell using nib, then in attributes inspector of cell, you can see a attribute "selection". set this to none.

if ur creating programmatically, then set your cell as

```
yourCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a view with same size of the cell. Apply background color to that view. Then set the view as the selected background of your cell in cellForRowAtIndexpath delegate method.

```
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:yourView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write these line in this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath



if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView  = bgView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign new UIView to cell's selectedBackgroundView with desired color.
**Swift 3**

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "departmentCell", for: indexPath)

        let selectedView = UIView(frame: cell.frame)
        selectedView.backgroundColor = ColorKit.cellSelectionColor
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView



        return cell
    }
```